# How to send ether from msg.sender to another address from within the contract

Tags: transfer, solidity-0.8.x, msg.sender

I'm new to solidity and I'm currently experimenting with smart contracts. As shown in the code below (only a part), I want to write a contract that lets you borrow money by paying a fee. I implemented the borrowing, but was not able to make the msg.sender pay a fee, by transferring eth from his account to another address for now. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

function borrow(uint256 _amountBorrow) public {
    uint256 fee = 0.001 ether;

    payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amountBorrow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the code:

1. You are sending the funds back to the caller of the function. msg.sender is the one who invokes the function. So if you invoke the function, msg.sender will have your address. To solve this problem, you could provide another parameter with a destination address.
2. In case this is a standalone function, you will have to you msg.value to send the Ether to a destination address.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
contract Borrow {
   function borrow(uint256 _amountBorrow, address destination) public payable {
       uint256 fee = 0.001 ether;

       payable(destination).transfer(msg.value);
   }
}
```

---

So, the idea is to borrow Ether from a contract. In order to borrow the user has to pay a fee.

In order to borrow Ether from the contract, the following code helps:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
contract Borrow {
   function borrow(uint256 _amountBorrow) public payable {
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amountBorrow);
   }
}
```

Now we will add the payment of a fee. The requirement is that the fee comes from the sender's account. This means, that the sender has to send some Ether in the value field of the transaction. In the contract, we can use the `msg.value` field to check how many Ether the sender attached to the transaction.

```
contract Borrow {
   function borrow(uint256 _amountBorrow) public payable {
       uint256 fee = 0.001 ether;
       require(msg.value == fee, 'Insufficient to cover fees');
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amountBorrow);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I indeed intended to send the funds back to (msg.sender) since he is borrowing from the smart contract balance, so it is function by itself. Could you kindly explain to me in more in detail the second point you wrote about. I'm still confused on about how to transfer the eth from the caller to another address. Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it explains and helps :)

Comment: Yes! I clearly understand now.  Please allow me to disturb you one more time. I'm using remix to compile and deploy the code. I used your input above in my code. However I keep getting the error, "execution reverted: "Insufficient to cover fees"". In my understanding, it seems that the msg.value is not actually sent yet. I used this to send it: `payable(feeAdress).transfer(fee);`                                                                                                          Thanks.

Comment: Actually I managed to find a way to a value to message right in Remix. Anyways, thank you for all your help. Really Really appreciate it! Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to figure it out :) Would you consider this answer as acceptable, then mark it as such, please.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest doing it with the `call` function from the `address` type:

```
(bool _sent, bytes memory _data) = msg.sender.call{value: _amountBorrow}("");
require(_sent, "Failed to send ether");
```